# How to concatenate to a string field of a document in firebase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update my firestore database with a long string of space separated values, after going through the docs I am using the following code to get to the "booked" field of my database:

```
  db.collection("seats")
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().getString("booked"));
      });
    });
```

This is the structure of my firebase database:
[image: Firestore DB]
I want to concatenate strings to this booked field, but I can not even access it. I get the folllowing error when I do so:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc.data(...).getString is not a function
```

How do I access and then concatenate some text to this field on my firestore database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc.data(...).getString is not a function
```

as error clearly says there is no method `getString()` associated with doc.data().

To get the field value from the response you can use below code

```
 db.collection("seats")
.get()
.then(function (querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().booked);

    // console.log("Booked",doc.data().get("booked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I got confused because the documentation said the fucntion was getString, but again , how do I concatenate my string to the database value after I get it?

Comment: I would add to pepe's answer the fact that you can alternatively use the [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get) method, which "retrieves the field specified by fieldPath". I.E. `doc.get("booked")`.

Comment: @DivyanshSingh It is not clear what you mean by "concatenate my string to the database value after I get it"

Comment: @RenaudTarnec ,Sorry,  so I am basically making a movie booking clone,[codepen](https://codepen.io/divi7/pen/zYvbbVN), and I want to change the booked seats colour to blue, for that I want the database to hold seat numbers for  all booked seats. This can only happen if I update the string("booked") on my database to store the name of all the seats that are booked, that is why I want to concatenate to it another string (which shall be the name of booked seats), but for the simplicity of the question , I only asked how I can concatenate a string to another firebase string field.

Comment: " I only asked how I can concatenate a string to another firebase string field." -> only in the front end? or you want to write it back to the db?

Comment: I want to write it to the db